# Implementing JS FloatThread plugin, to fix table header

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I was hoping someone could explain to me how to implement the FloatThread JS table plugin to my web page.

Currently I have a very long table which, when scrolled down becomes confusing to read - so I decided to try and implement a solution that would fix the first row (`<th>`tags) to the top of the table while scrolling down.

Here is my table code:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">  


            <div class="table-responsive"> 
            <table class="table table-bordered table-striped sortable">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th width="3%"></th>
                    <th>FINISH NO.</th>
                    <th>COLOUR</th>
                    <th>PURITY</th>
                    <th>CARAT</th>
                    <th>PRICE US $</th>
                    <th>FLUO</th>
                    <th>CUT</th>
                    <th>SYM</th>
                    <th>POLISH</th>
                    <th>NATTS</th>
                    <th>GIRDIE</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>Steven Spielberg</td>
                    <td>21.1.2004</td>
                    <td>17.38</td>
                    <td>16.69</td>
                    <td>34.07</td>
                    <td>16.69</td>
                    <td>34.07</td>
                    <td>17.38</td>
                    <td>16.69</td>
                    <td>34.07</td>
                    <td>17.38</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>Steven Spielberg</td>
                    <td>21.1.2004</td>
                    <td>17.38</td>
                    <td>16.69</td>
                    <td>34.07</td>
                    <td>16.69</td>
                    <td>34.07</td>
                    <td>17.38</td>
                    <td>16.69</td>
                    <td>34.07</td>
                    <td>17.38</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>Steven Spielberg</td>
                    <td>21.1.2004</td>
                    <td>17.38</td>
                    <td>16.69</td>
                    <td>34.07</td>
                    <td>16.69</td>
                    <td>34.07</td>
                    <td>17.38</td>
                    <td>16.69</td>
                    <td>34.07</td>
                    <td>17.38</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>Steven Spielberg</td>
                    <td>21.1.2004</td>
                    <td>17.38</td>
                    <td>16.69</td>
                    <td>34.07</td>
                    <td>16.69</td>
                    <td>34.07</td>
                    <td>17.38</td>
                    <td>16.69</td>
                    <td>34.07</td>
                    <td>17.38</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>Steven Spielberg</td>
                    <td>21.1.2004</td>
                    <td>17.38</td>
                    <td>16.69</td>
                    <td>34.07</td>
                    <td>16.69</td>
                    <td>34.07</td>
                    <td>17.38</td>
                    <td>16.69</td>
                    <td>34.07</td>
                    <td>17.38</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I came across a solution; at http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/ and downloaded the .zip and copied across the jquery.floatThread.min.js and jquery.floatThread.js files into my /js/ folder, included them in the page's header along with jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.floatThead.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write("\<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js' type='text/javascript'>\<\/script>");
</script>
```

and to the best of my ability I followed the usage examples and added the following `<script>` above my table:

```
<script>$('table.table-bordered.table-striped.sortable').floatThead({
scrollingTop: pageTop,
// I need this offset because I don't
// want the table header to overlap
//my site navigation (its a global function)
useAbsolutePositioning: false
// absolutePositioning is better for
// highly dynamic sites
// (which this is not)
});
</script>
```

but when I reload my page, the tables behave the same way. Can you see what I'm doing wrong / explain how to fix it for future reference?

For a reference, this is how they're supposed to function:

http://mkoryak.github.io/floatThead/#examples

Thanks!

Comment: `pageTop` is likely undefined because it only exists on the demo page, you are adding jquery after the jquery plugin and you dont have a document ready function... you need to start with the basics I think